# Is “horizontal slits” an acceptable description?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, technology

Sometimes on tv or while seeing an old video, there are slits on the screen, interrupting the video. It is like static. Is it okay to say “horizontal slits on screen” to describe this type of error? Is it clear?

Here is an example: https://youtu.be/dV-A9BDd1HY (00:46)

This will be very helpful.

Comment: Horizontal bars would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you, Xanne. Do you think “slits” is accurate, if not idiomatic? I think it conveys the sense that the screen is cut in many parts, which is the case.

Comment: They're not really slits in that they're not holes through to a space behind the picture, they're more a kind of interference on top of the picture.

Comment: I would use 'lines' if they were narrow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.

Comment: Nothing has been cut or separated. It wasn't filmed with those lines. They are simply artifacts of either the old equipment that was used or the deterioration of the film medium itself.

Comment: @JasonBassford - That's "noise".  It likely was present during the taping, possibly resulting from the equipment being jostled when the attempt occurred.  You don't see this "artifact" much anymore with digital broadcasts, but it was not at all unusual in 1987 when this event occurred.

Comment: If you want a non-technical term I'd probably go with "streaks" or "streaking".

Answer (score 2):

They're not slits.

**slit** - A long narrow cut or opening.

The best answer to your question would account directly for the cause of those markings. Not knowing the cause, I can only supply a couple terms at some remove from specificity.

1. **markings** (The most general)
2. **streak** - A long thin usu. irregular line or band of contrasting colour.

Comment: Yes, the key thing about a slit is that it lets something go through, whether light, water, mail, arrows/bullets, etc.